# Design of a medical stock management database (MLD)

Tags: database-design, database-schema

The project I want to realize is a web application for the stock management of a hospital.

The idea is that during the intervention on the patient, we scan the products (that we have in our stock)
that we use during the procedure, so that we can link all the products that we have used to the patient.

Being a novice in database construction, I made a schema of it.
Could you tell me what you think of it and why not what modifications you would make.

[MLD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTSXn.png)

Comment: One thing I'd change for sure is that you shoudn't mix up a patients treatment with the patient core data itself: `email` and `phone` is not a fact about the medical treatment and the invoice related to them.

Comment: Please ask specific questions, rather than "what do you think". At the very least, describe the business domain and ask about whether the design is compatible with the business domain.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, I don't see any changes that you should make. All the tables you make should have what you need. If you need to store the blood type of a patient, added it (I see you have it, but I said that so you can understand what I mean).

You made a (very) small mistake: in **doctor > medical_procedure > date** you put **date** instead of **datetime** (I think you need the time too there, so the date of the procedure is more accurate)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will make the changes you suggest. See you later :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your schema.

I can't comment on the relationships however I can see some obvious problems lying in wait for you.

- Your `varchar` columnns should be specified for the correct size for the data you expect. 255 characters for a phone number? 20 would suffice, Zipcode 60 characters - 10 surely?
- Price as an int? So you always work in whole dollars...
- Product type, Deposit type etc ... best served by an int I suspect
- Barcode - usually 13 digits not 255
- Amount as a varchar... no, that will bite you in the future
- You have `datetime` for some date columns, `date` for others, both named 'date'
- Name instead of first name and last name? find me all the Doctors who's surname begins 'S'... oh!

You don't state your target database platform, however getting the data types wrong and arbitrarily long field lengths can lead to bad execution plans and poor performance.

I think you need to carefully review this.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will make the changes you suggest.

Indeed I did not specify it but I wish to make this database with MySQL

Comment: Everything above is general good practice, especially with consistency between data types and correct types for monetary values!